# Meteor.js automatically logs in when i create a custom user

Tags: meteor

Lately having this issue when i create a new user using the Accounts.create() , it creates the new user and logs in automatically by that username.
It should just create the user and not login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [intended behavior](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser).  To create a new user without logging the client in, I'd write a [`Meteor.methods`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) which calls `Accounts.createUser` from the server side and call this method from the client, which will not result in the client being logged in.

**UPDATE**

To expand that a little, something like this:

#### server

```
Meteor.methods({
  createUser: function(options) {
    Accounts.createUser(options);
  }
});
```

#### client

```
Meteor.call('createUser', options, callback);

// THIS SHOULD REPLACE:
// Accounts.createUser(options, callback); on the client (callback is optional)
```

As per the link above, if you create a user from the server side it won't automatically log them in, as it doesn't know which client they're being created from.

Comment: kinda new to this..should i call the Accounts.createUser() inside Meteor.methods ?

Comment: let me give this a try